# Rigorous derivation of expected proportion of collisions

Tags: probability

The problem: $S$ is a finite set of $n$ elements. $H$ is a random function from $S$ to $S$ (the image $y\in S$ of each $x\in S$ by $H$ is chosen uniformly at random, with each choice independent; in cryptographic terms, $H$ is a [Random Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle)).

1. What is the limit (as $n\to\infty$) of the expected proportion of elements $x$ of $S$ such that $\exists x'\in S, H(x)=H(x')$?
2. What is the limit (as $n\to\infty$) of the expected proportion of elements $y$ of $S$ such that $\exists x\in S, \exists x'\in S, x\ne x', H(x)=y=H(x')$?

Note: expectancy is defined over the set of all $n^n$ functions $H$.

I know a non-rigorous way to derive the answers:

- a particular $y\in S$ is reached by no $x$ with odds exactly $(1-1/n)^n$, and the limit of that as $n\to\infty$ is $u=1/e$; that is also (but here I am not rigorous) the limit (as $n\to\infty$) of the expected proportion of elements of $S$ never reached;
- a particular $y\in S$ is reached by exactly one $x$ with odds exactly $(1-1/n)^{n-1}$ (obtained by summing the odds that it is reached by each particular $x$, and by no other $x'$), and the limit of that as $n\to\infty$ is $v=1/e$; that is also (but here I am not rigorous) the limit (as $n\to\infty$) of the expected proportion of elements of $S$ reached exactly once;
- it follows that the limit thought in (1.) is $1-v=1-1/e$, and the limit thought in (2.) is $1-u-v=1-2/e$.

Problem is, when going from the odds for a particular $y$, to the expected proportion of $y$ in $S$, this ignores that the probabilities considered are dependent. How can that be made rigorous?

---

If we where asked the same questions without *"the limit (as $n\to\infty$) of"*, and answered $\approx1-(1-1/n)^{n-1}$ and $\approx1-(1-1/n)^n-(1-1/n)^{n-1}$, can we bound how large the error is?

Comment: You say "$H$ is a random function from $S$ to $S$." Can you tell us something more about $H$? Is it a random *bijection*? Is the probability that $H(s) = s'$ independent of $s$ and $s'$? From what distribution on the set of all functions was $H$ chosen? Without this information, the question is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: @John Hughes: done.

Comment: Is (1.) supposed to be the expected number of elements of $S$ reached by at least one $H(s)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any particular function $f$, Consider an indicator variable $u_{f,x}$ which is $1$ if there's an $x' \ne x$ with $f(x) = f(x')$, and $0$ otherwise.

Note that this is a random variable on $F \times S$, where $F$ is the space of all $n^n$ possible functions.

Now look at the expected value (with respect to $f$) of 
$$
Q_f = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x u_{f,x},
$$
which is the fraction of elements in $X$ that are "hit twice" under $f$.

Use the fact that expectation is linear, and that you can swap sums. I believe that the result falls out. (Indeed, I think you've already got the proof). The "ignores probabilities that are dependent" is exactly the kind of thing for which linearity of expectation tends to be so useful.

Here's a simple example: on the set $S = \{0, 1\}$, let $X(s) = s$ and $Y(s) = 1-X(s)$. Clearly $X$ and $Y$ are not even slightly independent. But what is $E(X + Y)$? It's just $E(X) + E(Y) = 0.5 + 0.5 = 1$.